# Copy column value with multiple people to another list?

Tags: workflow

I have two list
1) Title, Section, State, Persons
2) Title, Persons

In list 1 Section is a lookup of Title in list 2. When I save an item in List 1 I want a workflow that updates the Item I just created with the Persons in list 2 that corresponds to the Section selected. Is this possible? I had a quick look but when I set it up I got a warning saying that if multiple items are returned only the first one will be used for update. How can I work around this and get all persons from one item in list 2 into Persons in list 1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually require a workflow ? such value propagation is very easy to implement with a custom event receiver

Comment: No custom code allowed in this case unfortunately

Comment: Gah, by default people picker does not allow multiple persons, I just changed it and now it works fine. I know there wont we duplicate Titles in List 2.

Comment: if you find the answer, answer to your question in order to mark it as answered

Comment: I am working on this to and I can't figure out how to update the column with multiple items. Can you please explain to me how did you get it work? Thank you very much