# Workflow to copy multiple people from list to another list

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

Similar to [this question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38928/copy-column-value-with-multiple-people-to-another-list) but different. It seems that person had a multiple entry people field in list one and had accidently not turned on multiple entry for the corresponding column in list two. We purposefully want list one to have multiple entries, but list two to have only one -- but more records if need be. Basically a 1 to many relationship.

We have SharePoint 2013, but can only use 2010 workflows. I assume that we will need designer workflows because this doesn't sound like something out of the box. I think I need a list workflow not a site workflow, is that correct?

We have list one:

1. Project name
2. Assigned to (blank, single person, or multiple people)
3. other info that isn't important to the copying/updating question

We want to copy this into list two:

1. Person (single)
2. Project assigned to
3. other information that will be added later and isn't important to the question

So if a project entry in list one is created/editing, but has nobody assigned to it, nothing needs to happen.

Whenever a person or persons are added to the "assigned to" column in list one then a record for each person or persons assign in list one needs to be created in list two. For example, if three people are assigned in a project in list one then three records will need to be created in list two.

If the person or persons assigned to a project in list one change or are updated list two needs to add/delete records to keep it in synch.

I've been able to get a workflow to copy a single person entry from list one into list two. But I'm not seeing how to grab the possibly multiple person value in list one and keep copying until I've done enough in list two.

First step is getting it to copy. Second step is getting it to delete update. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Visual Studio is an option, I would suggest looking at creating a VS event receiver.

Comment: Visual studio isn't an option -- or at least not as far as I know. We don't have it and as far as I know the free version can't be used for this, can it?

Comment: I'm guessing you would need the full version.  Not sure though.